# Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HMErrorDomain error 4.)"

Tags: ios, error-handling, homekit

I am using **HomeKit** and I get:

> Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (HMErrorDomain error 4.)"

I had a look at the Apple documentation and haven't found anything explaining what **error 4** means.

Anyone knows it?

And if so, is there a reference table (somewhere) explaining what the various HMErrorDomain code mean?

This is the [Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HomeKit_Constants/) I found which does not help.

**CODE THAT TRIGGERS IT:**

```
[characteristic writeValue:value completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                    }
                    else    {
                        NSLog(@"written");
                    }
                }];
```

Comment: It tells you: "The operation couldn’t be completed".

Comment: @Droppy Ah ah, thanks. I got that.. but there are different reasons why and the error code is meant to allow you understand them and fix the reason. Any idea on where a good error code table for HMErrorDomain is?

Comment: I agree the error text is not very descriptive at all.  What operation couldn't be completed?  Why couldn't it be completed?  Are you sure there are no other exceptions in the `userInfo` property of that error?

Comment: The userInfo is not passed in the callback method (I added a edit to show the code). I am just a bit puzzled that Apple won't include a reference table on the various HMErrorDomain errors. Yesterday I came across a different one and I figured out what triggered it (thanks to the community here) but today is more obscure..

Comment: I am talking about `NSError.userInfo`.  It's a dictionary that can optionally contain another `NSError` object which is the root cause of the error.  I am fairly certain `[NSError localizedDescription]` would reveal it, so start by using that method to get the text of the `NSError` object instead of `description`.

Comment: Please get `error.localizedDescription`. Printing the description of NSError doesn't help at all as @Droppy said.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: HMErrorCode is finally documented, so you can compare the errors to those values. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/homekit/hmerror.code

Homekit errors are pretty useless. For some reason, apple doesn't ever provide useful descriptions, just codes. There is a file provided as part of the HMCatalog sample app that provides useful(er) descriptions of HK errors, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Listings/HMCatalog_Supporting_Files_Utilities_NSError_HomeKit_m.html

Comment: The URL is invalid.